# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3' on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, web3py

I am trying to run the following code in Jupyter Notebook using Anaconda (I used pip to install web3):

```
from web3 import Web3
w3=web3.Web3(web3.Web3.HTTPProvider("http://172.18.0.1:8545"))
w3=util.connect(host="172.18.0.8",port="8545",poa=True)
assert w3.isConnected()
```

However, I get this Error Stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0c63a16e1a59> in <module>
----> 1 from web3 import Web3
      2 
      3 w3=web3.Web3(web3.Web3.HTTPProvider("http://172.18.0.1:8545"))
      4 w3=util.connect(host="172.18.0.8",port="8545",poa=True)
      5 assert w3.isConnected()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3'
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Comment: It is possible that conda env is different from env in wich you install the web 3? You try to do `!pip install web3`into the notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to find the answer myself with the help of @NicolaLandro: I did not use the command in the notebook.

However it worked, when I tried `pip install web3` inside the conda prompt, after activating conda environment.